# How to use user input statements in turtle module?

Tags: python, pycharm, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write a program in which the user inputs the number of lines who should than be displayed on turtle graphics window.

My problem is that the python turtle graphics windows closes itself as soon as I want to type the number of lines in the pycharm console. After I enter the number, the turtle graphics window does not show up again and pycharm shows that the programm is still running.

The code looks as follows:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()

babbage = turtle.Turtle()

babbage.shape("triangle")

n = int(input("How many legs should this sprite have? "))

angle = 360 / n

for i in range(n):

    babbage.right(angle)
    babbage.forward(65)
    babbage.stamp()

    babbage.right(180)
    babbage.forward(65)
    babbage.right(180)

babbage.shape("circle")

wn.exitonclick()
```

Comment: (1) How does `pycharm` enter into this program?  You don't import it, and it's not part of the program launch.  (2) As given, the code does not exhibit the error.  I get the requested quantity of arms, and the turtle screen stays until I click on it.

Comment: (1) I am using pycharm IDE to write the code down and pycharm terminal to execute it, but i have the problem that my input is not displayed on the python turtle graphics window and that the window dissappears. (2). The code seems to be fine as it is given in the book "How to think as a computer scientist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take the PyCharm console out of the picture and try it this way:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()

try:
    n = int(screen.numinput("Define Sprite", "How many legs should this sprite have?", default=4, minval=1, maxval=8))

except TypeError:
    exit()

angle = 360 / n

babbage = Turtle()
babbage.shape('triangle')

for _ in range(n):

    babbage.right(angle)
    babbage.forward(65)
    babbage.stamp()
    babbage.backward(65)

babbage.shape('circle')

screen.exitonclick()
```

Does that fix your problem?

Comment: It works your way, ty for your help :) I reinstalled Pycharm IDE and it works also with my initially code.